# How do I upgrade from a previous version of websauna?

Tags: pyramid, pylons, websauna

I have a websauna project which I created using this command:

```
   pip install -e "git+https://github.com/websauna/websauna.git@master#egg=websauna[celery,utils,notebook]"
```

this is found in the documentation at: https://websauna.org/docs/tutorials/gettingstarted/tutorial_02.html

This is the development version on github, and I recall it was alpha4. How do I upgrade this to the latest version(presumably at alpha5 as of this writing)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to install the latest release from the PyPi do:

```
  pip uninstall websauna
  pip install -U "websauna[celery,utils,notebook]"
```

If you want to follow the latest Github master branch:

```
  pip uninstall websauna
  pip install e "git+https://github.com/websauna/websauna.git@master#egg=websauna[celery,utils,notebook]"
```

Uninstall step might or might not be required depending on if you are switching between pip PyPi package install and `pip -e`.